# How to pass parameters in Angular between pages

Tags: angular, parameters, routes, ngoninit

My Node.js backend returns the AWS Cognito tokens as JSON which are received in my Angular `login` Component.

I wish to open my `dashboard` and pass the received tokens
in my `login.component.ts` function I do: `this.router.navigate(['/dashboard', { tokens: data }]);` before sending the data I print it to the console and it looks fine

in my `dashboard.component.ts` I'm not sure why the tokens are not reachable

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}   

ngOnInit() {

this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
            console.log('params = ' + params);
            var data = params['tokens'];
            console.log('data = ' + data);
            for(let key in data){
                console.log('key = ' + key + ' data= ' + data[key]);
            }
        });
}
```

this is the 'console.log' output `params = [object Object]` `data = undefined`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending params not query params, so your code should be :-

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            console.log('params = ' + params);
            var data = params['tokens'];
            console.log('data = ' + data);
            for(let key in data){
                console.log('key = ' + key + ' data= ' + data[key]);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I still can't access the tokens this is the `console.log`
params = [object Object]
data = undefined

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: don't know how to create one